# Android: Amplify SignOut closes app before actually signin out

Tags: android, logging, uri, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I decided to use Amplify on a school project, after I went through the Login process following this guide: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/signin/q/platform/android/
And also after adding the social sign in: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social_signin_web_ui/q/platform/android/

After following these guides I decided to also add a signout feature and test it out: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/signOut/q/platform/android/

It should have worked fine but when i lauch the signout method in the guide (literally after copying and pasting it in the project) the app closes as soon as I test it, and it isn't even consistent with the errors, the usual pattern is: it closes, after a while the console says that the signout timed out (obviously) when I reopen the app from the VM it says that it signout successfully then crashes giving this error (the project is called natour):

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.natour, PID: 7330
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.natour/com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoauth.activities.CustomTabsManagerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3400)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3440)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2713)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1516)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4507)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4475)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoauth.activities.CustomTabsManagerActivity.onResume(CustomTabsManagerActivity.java:69)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1269)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6766)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3377)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3440) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2713) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

I tried different things, thinking that if the login worked just fine, then something weird happened for the logout redirect uri, but nope, i changed it with "amplify update auth" on the console, changed the callback uri and nothing appened, the same error, the login worked just fine too even though I wrote an activity that wasn't even launched.
I changed the manifest because maybe the custom tab manager activity gave problems but to no avail (meaning it either gives far worse problems to which I know the cause or the same)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.natour">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <data android:scheme="natour" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />

        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NaTour">

        <activity
            android:name=".view.TransazioneRegister"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".visualizza_foto_inserite"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".visualizza_segnalazioni_effettuate"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".visualizza_itinerari_inseriti"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".visualizza_recensioni_inserite"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.InserimentoItinerario"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.Profile"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.Register"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.Login"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.VisualizzaItinerario"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.TabActivity"
            android:exported="false" /> <!-- Facebook Requirements -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.amplifyframework.auth.cognito.activities.HostedUIRedirectActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="natour"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.Signout"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="natour"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <!--<activity
            android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoauth.activities.CustomTabsRedirectActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="natour" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>-->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is the manifest in the *final* attempt, after that i gave up.

I searched this problem online and even though they got pretty close to our problem, either they didn't show the solution, the code is written in other programming language, they didn't explain what was going on. I hope to find some help here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been a while but I found that you need to change `launchMode`. I tried `singleTask` it works fine. Maybe `singleInstance` also works. But I get a time out error: `Timed out while waiting for sign-out redirect response`.
I found amplify is difficult to deal with because lack of documents and potential bugs, maybe also because not many people use it.